# Python tkinter raise exceptions and wait for button press

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new in Tkinter and I'm currently trying to create a small game. When something happens in the game I want to create a pop-up window which will inform the user about any changes. This is the code that I have written for it.

```
def message(self, text):
    top = tkinter.Toplevel(width=50, height=25)
    top.title("Message")
    msg = tkinter.Message(top, text=text)
    msg.pack()
    ok = tkinter.Button(top, text="OK", command=top.destroy)
    ok.pack()
```

My two questions are:

1. Can I replace this by an exception that will create an "Error Message" window? If it isn't necessary then can I use it to be raised by the exception?
2. I want the user to be forced to see and read the message, so how can I freeze the main window(the user can't click on anything else) until he presses the OK button on the pop-up window?

Comment: Look into [tkmessagebox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm).  If all you need is a popup with a simple message then these will save you some time having to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
top.grab_set()
```

To show `Error Message` you can use `tkmessagebox.showerror()`.